# Starting minimalistic standalone cassandra is not working via "cassandra -f"

Tags: cassandra

The latest `cassandra` was downloaded from the website. I am following the directions at https://medium.com/@areeves9/cassandras-gossip-on-os-x-single-node-installation-of-apache-cassandra-on-mac-634e6729fad6

Cassandra *is* installed:

```
22:26:40/cassandra $cassandra -v
3.11.4
```

I am starting `cassandra` as follows:

```
2:23:04/cassandra $bin/cassandra -f
```

However this is failing when trying to find the `cassandra.config`:

```
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]. Found[cassandra.yaml]. Please prefix the file with [file:///] for local files and [file://<server>/] for remote files. If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config]. Found[cassandra.yaml]. Please prefix the file with [file:///] for local files and [file://<server>/] for remote files. If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:80)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:100)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:268)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:147)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:132)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.applyConfig(CassandraDaemon.java:665)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:609)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:732)
```

Here is the directory info:

```
22:23:34/cassandra $pwd
/opt/cassandra
22:23:39/cassandra $ll conf
total 304
drwxr-xr-x@  3 sboesch  admin     96 Feb  2 14:09 triggers
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin   1603 Feb  2 14:09 metrics-reporter-config-sample.yaml
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin   3809 Feb  2 14:09 logback.xml
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin   1195 Feb  2 14:09 logback-tools.xml
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin   9956 Feb  2 14:09 jvm.options
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin   2757 Feb  2 14:09 hotspot_compiler
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin   6360 Feb  2 14:09 cqlshrc.sample
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin   2082 Feb  2 14:09 commitlog_archiving.properties
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin  57672 Feb  2 14:09 cassandra.yaml
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin   1358 Feb  2 14:09 cassandra-topology.properties
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin   1200 Feb  2 14:09 cassandra-rackdc.properties
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin    148 Feb  2 14:09 cassandra-jaas.config
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin  12541 Feb  2 14:09 cassandra-env.sh
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin  18250 Feb  2 14:09 cassandra-env.ps1
-rw-r--r--@  1 sboesch  admin    291 Feb  2 14:09 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x@ 17 sboesch  admin    544 Mar 10 22:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  17 sboesch  admin    544 Mar 10 22:22 ..
```

I have ensured that the `conf` files are properly available under `<installation_home>/conf`.  The `cassandra.yaml` is untouched: it is the default contents from the `tar.gz` download.

Why is this simply not working out of the box (it used to be *that* easy to start up a standalone cassandra ..) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config file may be specified using `-D cassandra.config=<path>` as follows:

```
export CASSANDRA=/opt/cassandra
$cassandra  -D cassandra.config=file://$CASSANDRA/conf/cassandra.yaml
```

It can then start.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set a system variable like this:

System.setProperty("cassandra.config", "file:////cassandra.yaml");

Comment: This is a `java` command - but there's no java involved in starting cassandra afaict.  I'm looking for what to do on the `cassandra -f` command line

Comment: cassandra runs on java

Comment: OK - yes and I am using the `cassandra`  java api for reading/writing data. But for starting it up as _standalone ( not as _embedded_) then we need  a functioning command line instead of java properties that are used when an _embedded_ instance were used.  I'll give you an upvote since the info might be helpful to someone else.